# How to re-scale logit output values

Tags: r

This is going into statistics, however quite few question has been answered here on SO. If there will be objections I will remove this question asap.

I would like to re-scale logit values so that the output values are scaled so that the min value is 0 or close to 0 and max value close to 1.

Here is sample data

```
logit <- rlogis(100, location = 1, scale = 5)

y <- sort((1/(1+exp(-logit))))[40:(length(logit)-50)] # here removing the close to 0 and 1 to replicate the problem.
x <- 1:length(y)

data <- data.frame(y,x)

with(data, plot(y~x))
```

So would someone point me to `r package` or show otherwise how to approach this and re-scale these values? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want the min and max values to have large absolute values.

```
out_range <- c(-10,10)
L_sc1 <- (logit-min(logit))/diff(range(logit)) # rescale to [0,1]
L_sc2 <- out_range[1]+diff(out_range)*L_sc1    # rescale to (min,max)
```

Plot results:

```
plot(sort(plogis(L_sc2)))
```